# Cross Platform Differences Parsing Google Protocol Buffers with Ruby

Tags: ruby, cross-platform, protocol-buffers

I'm having an issue with parsing the information from a Google Protocol Buffer binary.

The scenario is: 
I have two computers, a Mac and a PC. 
They are both running Ruby 2.0.0p481. 
They both have the ruby-protocol-buffers gem, version 1.5.1.
The protocol buffer binary file is 219 bytes on both computers, which leads me to believe that their contents are exactly the same. 
I have the same ".proto" files on both computers, as well as the same pb.rb files that I am using to interpret the protocol buffer binary. 
I wrote a short script that uses the auto-generated pb.rb files to parse the binary file, and have the same copy of the script on both computers.

However, when I run the script that interprets the binary file, the outputs are different on the Mac versus the PC.

When I run the script on the Mac, I get the exact information that I am expecting, which is all the information the protocol buffer contains. However, under the conditions mentioned above, when I run the same script on the Windows machine the output contains significantly less information.

I'm not sure why the output is so different, because I've made sure many of the variables (Ruby version, gem, gem version) are the same in both environments (Mac and PC). I also got the binary file individually on both the Mac and the PC from the same source at almost exactly the same time. I made sure to retrieve the binary file separately on both computers in case this might be an issue with line endings across Mac/PC, but it does not seem to make any difference.

What is causing this difference in output between Mac and PC?

Comment: If you want answers rather than guesses you'd be better off showing how to reproduce the problem (eg what's the input, how do the results differ). See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @Frederick Cheung. I need to keep my code confidential, so I cannot provide specific details. I am hoping that someone will be able to provide a list of environment variables or subtle differences between PC and Mac operating systems that would be relevant in this context and that I can use to further troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Is the binary file a representation of strings?  Are you sure this is not a character encoding problem?  The output containing less information could indicate to either unprintable characters or a multibyte character set on the Windows machine?

Comment: @conorliv you don't have to post your confidential code - merely code that reproduces the issue

Comment: Thank you for your advice, @Frederick Cheung. I'm new to asking questions on stackoverflow so it's helpful that you're showing me the ropes.

Comment: @mcfinnigan It was a character encoding problem that revolves around the fact that Unix systems do not have a "text" mode whereas Windows does. I was able to answer my own question, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question, here. Mainly by the help of the creator of the ruby-protocol-buffers gem.

He suggested: "It's possible you're hitting a problem with a file getting opened in text mode rather than binary mode."
See his full answer here:
https://github.com/codekitchen/ruby-protocol-buffers/issues/35#issuecomment-55759174

I then searched for how to open a file in Ruby in binary mode and found this stackoverflow question:
[Automatically open a file as binary with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929610/automatically-open-a-file-as-binary-with-ruby)

The following is a direct quote from that post:
While it's true that there is no "text" mode in Unix file systems, Ruby does make a difference between opening files in binary and non-binary mode:

```
s = File.open('/tmp/test.jpg', 'r') { |io| io.read }
s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

is different from (note the "rb")

```
s = File.open('/tmp/test.jpg', 'rb') { |io| io.read }
s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

The latter, as the docs say, set the external encoding to ASCII-8BIT which tells Ruby to not attempt to interpret the result at UTF-8. You can achieve the same thing by setting the encoding explicitly with s.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT'). This is key if you want to read binary into a string and move them around (e.g. saving them to a database, etc.).