# How to upload pdf files to server from ajax without rails on ruby 2.4

Tags: ruby

I have a function to submit a file to the server:

```
function _docs_submit() {
  event.preventDefault();
  upDOCS_btn.html("Uploading...");

  var files =  $("#upDOCS").prop('files'),
      formData = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    if (!file.type==='application/pdf') {
      continue;
    }

    formData.append('docs[]', file, file.name);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "medcon/adddocs",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (locks) {
      alert('Thank you.\nDocument(s) received.');
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert("There was an error submitting your documents:\n" + e.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

How should I capture that in ruby and save to the pdf to the server without using rails and on Ruby 2.4?

```
post 'medcon/adddocs' do |params|
  theFile = params[:data] # need help here
  #save file to server - need help here especially
end
```

I can use gems as long as they match with Ruby 2.4.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the framework you are using? Sinatra?

Comment: I do have sinatra and swagger_client

Comment: getting an error: 746: unexpected token at '------ WebKitFormBoundaryBQKXy1ANr8lLjtGg

Comment: also, when I do require sinatra, it kills the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the param values by key, use tic marks.  Here's the solution I went with, which includes a method for creating a file directory where it doesn't already exist.  To write the file use file.open and wb to write the file in binary mode.

```
require 'fileutils'

def create_folder(path)
  unless File.directory?(path)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(path)
  end
end

post 'medcon/adddocs' do |params, me|
 params = params['body']
   filename = params['data']['filename']
   fid = params['fid'].to_s
   file = Base64.decode64(params['data']['file_base64'])
   folder = "../data/medcon/fid#{fid}"

 create_folder folder # send folder path to create folder method

  File.open("#{folder}/#{filename}", 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(file)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the contents of uploaded file you use `file_param[:tmpfile]` and you can also access original filename under `file_param[:filename]` (not sure if you want to reuse it. Armed with that knowledge, you should be able to handle your upload with something like that (not tested, from memory):

```
post 'medcon/adddocs' do |params|
  files = param[:data][:docs] # or maybe string keys, I'm not sure
  files.each do |file|
    name = file[:filename]
    contents = file[:tmpfile].read
    File.open(File.join('/some/path', filename), 'wb') { |f| f.write(contents) }
  end
end
```

Comment: There are better ways to write a file in binary mode with Ruby: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929610/automatically-open-a-file-as-binary-with-ruby/34045118#34045118

Comment: So close katafrakt!  You pointed me int he right direction though